# Do I still need to purchase the MPEG-2 and VC-1 license keys for the Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, video, firmware, licensing

Do I still need to purchase the MPEG-2 and VC-1 license keys for the Raspberry Pi 2?

If so, will the same MPEG-2 and VC-1 licenses [available in the Raspberry Pi store](http://www.raspberrypi.com/license-keys/) work with the Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: It's said that the GPU stays the same, so I'd assume that the video codecs will still be needed. Though the increased computational power of the CPU might render them less necessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [Raspberry Pi 2 - FAQ and collated answers](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=683295#p683295)

> Do I still need CODEC licences?
>
> Yes, if you want to use the HW decoders. However, the higher speed of
>   the device MIGHT mean a SW decoder can be used. This will depend on
>   the resolution of the video you are trying to display.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still need it and for new Raspberry Pi you have to buy new license.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. in RPI 2 quad core you need the codec if you want to play video_ts files, you need to purchase the mpeg2 codec. Once purchased and add to config.txt then video_ts can be played perfectly with the menu settings just like you have with a DVD in a player.